# How to extract only JSON from a webpage?

Tags: command-line, json

As rendered, a webpage has solely or primarily JSON.

I want to save only all the JSON in it into a file.
Just take all JSON (even if it is organized in different "chapters").

How to do that?
Should I first download it as HTML with curl/wget and then use something like `jq` or directly `jq` or would it be better to just save from GUI and then process from command line?

Comment: If you are considering a specific static HTML file, consider providing an example. If you are instead considering a website that offers some form of document endpoint, then provide the URL for that website; the REST API that they use will likely provide a way of getting the data you require.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is already answered if you read the instruction

```
Specify the format parameter to change the output format. To see the non-HTML representation of the JSON format, set format=json.
```

`curl 'https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=specialpagealiases&formatversion=2&format=json' > file.json`

Comment: Your assumption that I mean solely to that webpage, is wrong.